# Why I can't load a 3rd party assembly on windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a wp8 app, and it uses a 3rd party control *assembly/library*. In debugging, it works very well, but after I installed the xap package to the device, it always crashed. The below is the crash stack trace:

> Exception message: Could not load file or assembly 'AMap.WP7.Map.API,
>   Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file  Stack trace:    at
>   Views.MyMapView.InitializeComponent() at Views.MyMapView..ctor()

What's wrong about it, and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:
- 'AMap.WP7.Map.API.dll , you may not have packaged and deployed OR
- 'AMap.WP7.Map.API.dll, the one that is installed on WP8 device, might be fully signed version, which means it does not have public key as null, and you might have linked to an assembly that as public key as null

Please check if 'AMap.WP7.Map.API.dll exists on device, if it does, then check its complete strong name, and ensure when you build your XAP you are linking to same assembly as the one that exists on device.

Note that even if you are packaging your linked assembly, if it already loaded in memory then CLR will not load, and since you have linked to different strong named assembly the load will fail, hence linking to same strong named assembly will resolve your issue.